# Deus Ex: Human Revolution - The Missing Link - Does it contain Spoilers?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution, the-missing-link

The DLC "The Missing Link" takes place in between the storyline of the main game. In my playthrough from the main game I am **not** that far (atm I am the second time in Detroit after Montreal).

What I want to know is, if I should play the DLC in between my main playthrough. Meaning, when Jensen gets knocked out and shipped to Singapore, I start playing the DLC and "pause" my main playthrough. Or should I rather finish the main game and *then* play the DLC.

The reason I am asking this, is because I want to know if the DLC contains any spoilers about the ending of the main game, which I am "not supposed to know" at that point in the main playthrough.

**Note:** Please try to avoid any spoilers, since I didn't finish the game yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - The Missing Link contains spoilers.

The Missing Link DLC stands apart as an episode by itself, even though the timeline in which is happens is during the main story; it takes place chronologically just before the last mission in the main story of Human Revolution.

Ideally, you want to play up to the last mission in Human Revolution, save your game, play through The Missing Link DLC, and then finish the last mission. Alternatively you can play through the whole of Human Revolution and then play The Missing Link [as explained in this existing answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/75124/27134) (contains spoilers).

I would not, however, play the DLC before the last mission as it does contain information explaining the story in the main game.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It wasn't my intention to play the DLC before reaching the relating point in the story. But you would recommend, when I reach the point where the DLC chronologically I should save and "pause" the game and play the DLC, and then finish the game afterwards? So the DLC does not contain any crucial spoilers about the main game ending?

Comment: No, the DLC takes place *before* the game ending, and contains no spoilers. I personally played the whole of Human Revolution through the weekend it was released, which was before the DLC came out, and then played the DLC but in terms of timing it fits into the main story just before the last mission starts.

Comment: I know that the DLC takes place before Singapore (unfortunately I read that much in a review). But the fact that the DLC takes place *before* the ending, doesn't necessarily mean that it wont hint out any clues about the ending (for example a treasury you would never have seen coming, or something like this). But since you say that the DLC does **not** contain such spoilers, I will play it *before* I finish the game.

Comment: Discussing a topic without spoilers makes me realise how hard it can be to explain something really simple without exposing huge portions of the story :P

Comment: Ahaha in the "Answer notification" i saw your old post where you said where the last mission takes place. But no probs, unfortunately I read that somewhere too ( but that's it I dont know what happens, so don't tell me anything more :X) ^^